# How to set Form API's password_confirm in/visible depending on prior select list input?

Tags: 7, forms, users

Neither `visible` nor `invisible` seems to work on `password_confirm`. Am I doing something wrong? What else can I try? This is my current code for a subadministrator form, where I'ld like to display the `password_confirm` only after a user is chosen:

```
$form['user_select'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#options' => array('' => '- ' . t('None') . ' -') + _get_users_by_role('Subadministration'),
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#description' => t('Chose account'),
);

$form['confirm_password'] = array(
  '#type' => 'password_confirm',
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#description' => t('Type same password in both fields'),
  '#states' => array(
    'invisible' => array(
      ':input[name="user_select"]' => array('value' => ''),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A container around the password_confirm did the trick! Fieldset works too.

```
$form['user_select'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#options' => array('' => '- ' . t('None') . ' -') + _get_users_by_role('Subadministration'),
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#description' => t('Chose account'),
);

$form['pass_wrapper'] = array(
    '#type' => 'container',
    '#states' => array(
      'invisible' => array(
        ':input[name="user_select"]' => array('value' => ''),
      ),
    ),
  );

$form['pass_wrapper']['confirm_password'] = array(
  '#type' => 'password_confirm',
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#description' => t('Type same password in both fields'),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

is the value ever getting `""`,try the following

```
 'invisible' => array(
   ':input[name="user_select"]' => array('value' => t('None')),
 ),
```

Comment: Doesn't work :(